# How to install PyQt5-tools on Python 3.8 (I can see only wersion for up to 3.7)

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8

I have Python 3.8 on Windows.
Already installed via pip PyQt5, tried PyQt5-tools but can't.
My PyQt5 version is: 5.13.1

```
pip install PyQt5-tools
```

gives the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5-tools(from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyQt5-tools
```

I checked the https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/#files and tried as they mention to do:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools==5.13.1.1.6rc0
```

or

```
pip install --pre pyqt5-tools~=5.13.1
```

gives same error as above.
The site mentions though Python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and no 3.8

I am assuming that its the matter of Python version. Am I right?
Or maybe it has to do with exact PyQt5 version?
Can somebody clarify me this? How to go through this problem?

Comment: There is no version of that library for Python3.8 so you have the following options: wait for the developer to test it or compile the project for python3.8 or use python 3.7.  Less than an hour ago they published an issue about it: https://github.com/altendky/pyqt5-tools/issues/35

Answer (score 2):

On Linux OSes (Debian Based) Use the following Command

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator pyqt5-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

For other platforms, use the website. You can download PyQt from their [official page](https://www.qt.io/download) and opt for the Qt Designer package, too. Depending on your options, you will have to complete the installation process, as mentioned in the PyQt website.

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded to Python 3.8 and had the same problem. If you need QT designer, you can find Windows and Mac executables (40 MB) on [this website](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed python 3.8 and pyQT5, then try looking for QTDesigner within the following subpath of your python directory:-

```
...\Python38\Library\bin\designer.exe
```

The location of the above path will depend on whether you have python installed just for you or for all users.  The full path for a single user installation is:

```
C:\Users\\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python38\Library\bin\designer.exe
```

The full path for an global installation of python is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38\Library\bin\designer.exe
```

It should already be there (it was for me).

You can alternatively try running `designer` launch command from the command prompt.

If you are using python through Anaconda, then from the Anaconda command prompt, type:

```
conda activate Your_Environment_Name
```

followed by

```
designer
```

Alternatively, you can find it here:

```
C:\Users\\%UserName%\\.conda\envs\GameDev\Library\bin\designer.exe
```