# Is PyQt5 available to Python 3.8? I can't install pyqt5-tools

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8

I can't use the command: "pip install pyqt5-tools" on my terminal. What is happening? My Python version?

The error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-tools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5-tools

Comment: read my coment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398255/how-to-install-pyqt5-tools-on-python-3-8-i-can-see-only-wersion-for-up-to-3-7

Comment: Isn't Python 3.8 brand new? I wouldn't be surprised to find packages that aren't ready yet.